# CUDA programming ---- how to understand the CudaDeviceReset()

Tags: cuda, gpu

In the past, I used to do GPU programming through Cublas which is a high-level API. Now I try to write a novice code as the following and I have a few questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void helloFromGPU()
{
    printf("Hello World from GPU!\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World from CPU!\n");

    helloFromGPU <<<1, 10>>>();
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I call the CudaDeviceReset() after the kernel function. I find that I cannot get the output message if I delete this line. I do not understand the reason for that. I see that the `cudaDeviceReset()` is to destroy the Cuda context and reset the device. Does it mean that the function also flushes my output buffer?

One more question, if I delete this line, I do not get any output to my screen. I believe that this is because of my program overs before the output from GPU comes to my screen. Is that right?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already found out why that happens.
To have the results of your kernel be visible to your code, you need to wait for it to finish.

cudaDeviceReset() is one of the functions that does that, but for the future you'll want to use

> cudaDeviceSynchronize()

or similar API functions which will let you wait for the kernel to finish without resetting the GPU.

Comment: Or another kernel launch, or a synchronous memcpy operation, or a stream suchronization call, or a stream callback, or one of several context operations. All are listed in the programming guide